# Spring Mongo aggregate request

Tags: spring, mongodb

I'm new with the mongo/spring-boot environment and I need some help for a short question:
My collection of **sales** contains:

```
{
    {"client": "MICKAEL", "article": "article1"},
    {"client": "MICKAEL", "article": "article1"},
    {"client": "MICKAEL", "article": "article2"},
    {"client": "JOHN", "article": "article1"},
    {"client": "JACK", "article": "article1"},
    {"client": "JACK", "article": "article2"},
}
```

So, with Mongo request

```
db.getCollection("sales").aggregate(
    [
      {"$group" : {_id: {client:"$client",article:"$article"}}},
      {"$group" : {_id: {client:"$_id.client"}, count:{$sum:1}}
    ]
)
```

I get the following result :

```
{"_id" : {"client" : "JACK"}, "count" : 2},
{"_id" : {"client" : "JOHN"}, "count" : 1},
{"_id" : {"client" : "MICKAEL"}, "count" : 2}
```

so how many different items each customer has. That's good.

No, I try since more hours to translate that with Spring boot (with the repository or with mongoOperations/aggregate request), without result.

Can you help me?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope your query is working fine. You can covert this with `MongoTemplate`.So you need to autowire it.

```
@Autowired
MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
```

The aggregation functions help you to convert this.

```
public List<Object> test(){
    Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
        group(
            Fields.from(
                    Fields.field("client", "$client"),
                    Fields.field("article", "$article")
            )
        ),
        group(
            Fields.from(
                    Fields.field("client", "$_id.client")
            )
        ).count().as("count")

    ).withOptions(AggregationOptions.builder().allowDiskUse(Boolean.TRUE).build());

    return mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(YOUR_COLLECTION.class), Object.class).getMappedResults();
}
```

I have't tested it, but it should work if your query is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much. I test your solution.